# After twice click only jquery is firing for ajax post method

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-post

I am using the ajax post method to send values from aspx to php.in that i am calling that ajax method a s function in the button click event after inserting the values in the db only i will call the script but when i click the second time only that script is calling how to fix it while clicking at at first time itself?and also this method is not working in the firefox but working in IE when clicking for the second time.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  function resetFields()
  {
     $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#<%=this.btnAdd.ClientID %>").click(function() {
    // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
    var ddlCompany = $("#<%=this.ddlCompany.ClientID %>").attr('value');
    var txtLocation = $("#<%=this.txtLocation.ClientID %>").attr('value');
    var txtDept = $("#<%=this.txtDept.ClientID %>").attr('value');
    var ddlIndustryType = $("#<%=this.ddlIndustryType.ClientID %>").attr('value');
    var txtDesg = $("#<%=this.txtDesg.ClientID %>").attr('value');
    var ddlFnalArea = $("#<%=this.ddlFnalArea.ClientID %>").attr('value');
    var txtExperience = $("#<%=this.txtExperience.ClientID %>").attr('value');
    var txtJobDesc = $("#<%=this.txtJobDesc.ClientID %>").attr('value');
    var txtEducation = $("#<%=this.txtEducation.ClientID %>").attr('value');
    var txtDesiredProfile = $("#<%=this.txtDesiredProfile.ClientID %>").attr('value');
    var txtPositionWanted = $("#<%=this.txtPositionWanted.ClientID %>").attr('value');
    var txtAddedBy = $("#<%=this.txtAddedBy.ClientID %>").attr('value');
    var txtContactName = $("#<%=this.txtContactName.ClientID %>").attr('value');
    var txtEmailid = $("#<%=this.txtEmailid.ClientID %>").attr('value');
    var txtContactno = $("#<%=this.txtContactno.ClientID %>").attr('value');
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
       url: "http://172.16.126.32/Riyas/marggroup.com/get-current-openings.php",
      data: "ddlCompany=" + ddlCompany + "& txtLocation="+ txtLocation+"& txtDept="+ txtDept+"& ddlIndustryType="+ ddlIndustryType+"& txtDesg="+ txtDesg+"& ddlFnalArea=" + ddlFnalArea+"& txtExperience="+ txtExperience+"& txtJobDesc="+ txtJobDesc+"& txtEducation="+ txtEducation+"& txtDesiredProfile="+ txtDesiredProfile+"& txtPositionWanted="+ txtPositionWanted+"& txtAddedBy="+ txtAddedBy+"& txtContactName="+ txtContactName+"& txtEmailid="+ txtEmailid+"& txtContactno="+ txtContactno,
      success: function(response){
        $('div.success').html(response);
      }
    });
       return false;
     });
    });
  }
  </script>
```

codebehind:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
c.MyQuery("insert into tblHrims_currentOpeningsNew(nvrDesignation,nvrCompany,nvrExperience,nvrLocation,nvrEducation,nvrDepartment,nvrIndustryType,nvrFnalArea,nvrJobDesc,nvrDesiredProfile,nvrContactPerson," +
" nvrContactNumber,nvrEmailId,nvrWantedPositions,nvrAddedBy,dttAddedon) values('" + txtDesg.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "") + "','" + ddlCompany.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + txtExperience.Text + "','" + txtLocation.Text + "','" + txtEducation.Text + "'," +
" '" + txtDept.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "") + "','" + ddlIndustryType.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + ddlFnalArea.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + txtJobDesc.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + txtDesiredProfile.Text.Replace("'", "") + "'," +
" '" + txtContactName.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "") + "','" + txtContactno.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "") + "','" + txtEmailid.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "") + "','" + txtPositionWanted.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "") + "'," +
" '" + txtAddedBy.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "") + "','" + c.GetValue("select getdate()") + "')");
      string strID = c.GetValue("select max(intsno) from tblhrims_currentopeningsNew");
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "reset", " resetFields();", true);
}
```

Comment: What is the resetFields function and when are you calling it? And why did you put $(document).ready(function(){ } code inside the resetFields function?

Comment: resetFields() function i am calling in the server side function

Comment: On another note, if the input is in a form, you can just put this line: ` var datastring = $("#myForm").serialize();`. Then you don't have to handle everything manually :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you can use `on` event handler in `jquery`. `live, bind and delegate` are deprecated in jquery 1.7.
2. you dont need to use `attr('value')` instead `val()` will work.
3. include `datatype = 'html'` in ajax call to denote that `response` will be in `html`.
4. Also you have kept `$(document).ready(function(){` inside the function `resetFields`. which is not needed.
5. remove function `resetFields` call from `button` element.

Then try using below code, i hope it will help you

```
String scriptString = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#<%=this.btnAdd.ClientID %>').on('click',function(){
    var ddlCompany = $('#<%=this.ddlCompany.ClientID %>').val();
    var txtLocation = $('#<%=this.txtLocation.ClientID %>').val();
    var txtDept = $('#<%=this.txtDept.ClientID %>').val();
    var ddlIndustryType = $('#<%=this.ddlIndustryType.ClientID %>').val();
    var txtDesg = $('#<%=this.txtDesg.ClientID %>').val();
    var ddlFnalArea = $('#<%=this.ddlFnalArea.ClientID %>').val();
    var txtExperience = $('#<%=this.txtExperience.ClientID %>').val();
    var txtJobDesc = $('#<%=this.txtJobDesc.ClientID %>').val();
    var txtEducation = $('#<%=this.txtEducation.ClientID %>').val();
    var txtDesiredProfile = $('#<%=this.txtDesiredProfile.ClientID %>').val();
    var txtPositionWanted = $('#<%=this.txtPositionWanted.ClientID %>')val();
    var txtAddedBy = $('#<%=this.txtAddedBy.ClientID %>').val();
    var txtContactName = $('#<%=this.txtContactName.ClientID %>').val();
    var txtEmailid = $('#<%=this.txtEmailid.ClientID %>').val();
    var txtContactno = $('#<%=this.txtContactno.ClientID %>').val();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://172.16.126.32/Riyas/marggroup.com/get-current-openings.php',
      data: 'ddlCompany='+ddlCompany+'&txtLocation='+txtLocation+'&txtDept='+txtDept+'&ddlIndustryType='+ddlIndustryType+'&txtDesg='+txtDesg+'&ddlFnalArea='+ddlFnalArea+'&txtExperience='+txtExperience+'&txtJobDesc='+txtJobDesc+'&txtEducation='+txtEducation+'&txtDesiredProfile='+txtDesiredProfile+'&txtPositionWanted='+txtPositionWanted+'&txtAddedBy='+txtAddedBy+'&txtContactName='+txtContactName+'&txtEmailid='+txtEmailid+'&txtContactno='+txtContactno,
      datatype = 'html',
      success: function(response){
        $('div.success').html(response);
        }
      });
   });
 });<s/cript>";
```

and

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "reset", scriptString, true);
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#<%=this.btnAdd.ClientID %>").on('click',function() { it is not working.in server side what should i do?

Comment: the jquery u send itself not all working i juast copied and tried not working

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("#&lt;%=this.btnAdd.ClientID %>").live('click', function() {
```

Hope it helps

Comment: "live" has been deprecated in jquery 1.7. Its not suggested to use it.

Comment: in server side what should i do?

Comment: you need not change anything regarding server side, just handle the post data

Comment: i have used this code but btton event in server side not working...it is not inserting

Comment: Then how to insert the values